# Automatically registering Django model in a separate table

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django app I have several models representing different types of content:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Playlist(models.Model):
    videos = models.ManyToManyField(Video)
```

Now I would like to create an easy way of adding `like`'s to instances of the two models, that can be easily set up like in the [django-vote](https://github.com/shanbay/django-vote) app:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    likes = LikeManager()

class Playlist(models.Model):
    videos = models.ManyToManyField(Video)
    likes = LikeManager()
```

But unlike the [django-vote method](https://github.com/shanbay/django-vote/blob/master/vote/managers.py#L159), which relies on a **single table** `Votes` linking all votes to different objects via `GenericRelation` field, I want to automatically create a separate table for each model, like `VideoLikes` and `PlaylistLikes`. This can have significant impact on performance when number of objects of either model becomes very large, or if other likeable models are added in the future.

Is there a way of abstracting to this level, or do I have to create an abstract `Like` model, and then create `VideoLike`, `PlaylistLike` inheriting from the abstract `Like` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably create your own factory that would do some introspecting and create a "like model" derived from your original, but down the road you will most likely need to handle those "like models" differently from one another depending on what you do with their respective underlying model. Plus, not having a defined model in `models.py` can lead to confusion and make the code harder to maintain.